# Windows Docker install oracle DB

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

Is there are possible way to install oracle DB in a native Windows docker container ?

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
COPY /WINDOWS.X64_180000_db_home.zip c:/data/db_home.zip
RUN powershell -command Expand-Archive c:\\data\\db_home.zip -DestinationPath c:\\data\\db_home
RUN setx path ".;c:\data\db_home\Bin;%path%;"
ENV ORACLE_HOME c:\\data\\db_home
COPY /vcredist_x64.exe c:/vcredist_x64.exe
RUN powershell.exe -Command \
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; \
Start-Process c:\vcredist_x64.exe -ArgumentList '/install /passive /norestart ' -Wait ; \
Remove-Item c:\vcredist_x64.exe -Forc
COPY db.rsp c:\\data\\db.rsp
RUN c:\data\db_home\setup.bat -silent -responseFile c:\data\db.rsp
ENV ORACLE_HOME c:\\data\\db_home
ENV ORACLE_SID orclcdb
ENV CLASSPATH c:\\data\\db_home\\jlib;c:\\data\\db_home\\rdbms\\jlib;
EXPOSE 5500 1521
COPY /scripts C:/data/app/myhome/admin/orclcdb
RUN c:/data/app/myhome/admin/orclcdb/scripts/orclcdb.bat
COPY post_install.bat c:/data/post_install.bat
CMD ["c:/data/post_install.bat"]
```

This is my current docker file. Have not managed to get the DB running.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. See [this posting](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/494#issuecomment-1409659929) from an Oracle employee. He also links to a presentation he did which has his Dockerfile.

The key point is that you must use Oracle Database 19.7 or later to get the bug fixes pertinent to Windows containers and silent installs. However for the Oracle client I have had success installing the Oracle 18 instantclient.